# Operations on power set

Tags: group-theory, monoid

Which kind of operations on a power set leads to a group/monoid?

Known to me are:
- intersection
- union
- symmetric difference
- complex product of a group

Ate there some more examples?

Comment: What is a complex product of a group?

Comment: If $G$ is a group with multiplikation $\cdot$ then for all subsets $A,B$ of $G$ the complex product is defined by $A\cdot B:=\{ a\cdot b \mid a\in A, b\in B \}$. So the multiplication of $G$ is transferred ton multiplication to the power set of $G$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The power set of any set becomes an Abelian group under the operation of symmetric difference, with the empty set as the neutral element of the group and every element in this group being its own inverse. The power set of any set becomes a Boolean ring with symmetric difference as the addition of the ring and intersection as the multiplication of the ring. [Here](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Symmetric_Difference_on_Power_Set_forms_Abelian_Group) is the proof, that symmetric difference on power set forms Abelian group. The proof of the statement that the power set of any set with intersection is commutative monoid [here](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Power_Set_with_Intersection_is_Commutative_Monoid).

Just for the curiosity the [*Ring of sets*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ring_of_sets) wikipedia article is also related.

Comment: Thanks for your answer in addition by DeMorgans rules the commutative monoids with intersection and union are isomorphic.

Comment: Are there any more examples especially for operations leading to groups on the power set?

Comment: Maybe there is. I don't know. By the way the concept of ring in measure theory is exactly this. The power set of a given set with symmetric difference as the addition and intersection as the multiplication. So the measure theoretically ring is a special case of the term *ring* in algebra.